# Use String as object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

Here I am dynamically getting a string like this:

```
  var datN="{y:12 ,marker: {symbol: 'url(http://abc.com//1446/t_23718.gif)'}},72.72727,83.333336";
```

I want to use it in HighChart api as graph data but this is not working. I have tried and got this that if the code was like this it would work:

```
  var datN=[{y:12 ,marker: {symbol: 'url(http://abc.com//1446/t_23718.gif)'}},72.72727,83.333336];
```

so how can I convert the first variable to work like the second one? I am new to javascript please help?

**UPDATE**

All I want is to convert the first string to object like second one (Second one is working correctly) . I have already tries JSON.parse and eval but they didnt work. So please help?

Comment: Where do you have gotten the first variable from?

Comment: Where are you getting the string from in the first place?

Comment: duplicate of [How to parse JSON in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)

Comment: @Bergi Not an exact duplicate, that string needs some working before being parsed.

Comment: I am getting that from a java method which I am using as data for highchart api

Comment: @MaxArt: Well yeah, that's why we were asking where he got it from so we can tell him how make that valid JSON :-)

Comment: @NavdeepSinghBedi: Then you should make that java method output [proper JSON](http://json.org/). Can you show us its code?

Comment: try eval("[" + datn.replace(/'/g, "\"") + "]");

Comment: Why you cannot encode array to JSON and return correct JSON object?

Comment: I have corrected my JSON using http://jsonlint.com/ easily and now it is running I am using the jquery parsing method.

Comment: So all works properly ? or something not ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var datArr = JSON.parse("[" + datN + "]");
```

This may not work across browsers because JSON.parse is not supported by all browsers. I think you could use jquery

```
var datArr = $.parseJSON("[" + datN + "]");
```

If it still does not work, you may try

```
var datArr = eval("[" + datN + "]");
```

Although this solution is not recommended.

Comment: Eval is acceptable as long as the string is sanitized. jQuery has a regex for that.

Comment: @Quentin: an array is still a valid json object. That's not correct?? If you look carefully, this is an array with 3 items. Am I missing something?

Comment: JSON requires property names to be strings (not identifiers) and for strings to be delimited with `"` not `'`.

Comment: @Quentin True. Well, eval then, but string has to be sanitized beforehand.

Comment: @Quentin: well, so in this case, only the eval works and it is the simplest solution

Comment: I have corrected my JSON using http://jsonlint.com/ easily and now it is running I am using the jquery parsing method.